# Kotlin - path in Activity when passed to Fragment shows up as null and then changes value

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a situation in which I am trying to pass the path from an Activity to a Fragment.  Below is a snippet of my MainActivity.kt file:

```
MainActivity.kt

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val myDir = File(getApplicationContext()?.getExternalFilesDir(null)?.toString() + "/")
        // below line displays the path
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "MainActivity: " + myDir.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("path", myDir.toString())
        // set MainActivityFragment Arguments
        val fragobj = MainActivityFragment()
        fragobj.setArguments(bundle)

        val manager = supportFragmentManager

        // Begin the fragment transition using support fragment manager
        val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()

        // add the fragment on container
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment, fragobj)

        // Finishing the transition
        transaction.commit()

        strPackName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
    }
```

And the MainActivityFragment.kt snippet that receives the info.

```
MainActivityFragment.kt

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val strPath = getArguments()?.getString("path")
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)

        // initially displays this value as null but then changes to value from MainActivity.kt
        Toast.makeText(getActivity()?.getApplicationContext(), "MainActivityFragment: " + strPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

The path value is initially displayed as null but then I get another Toast message saying that the value changes to the original value from MainActivity.  Is there a way to prevent this so that I get only one Toast message that displays the path value?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean toast is called twice??

Comment: First time display `MainActivityFragment:` ?

Comment: @Rahul it appears that way.  The Toast messages I am getting are MainActivityFragment: null and MainActivityFragment: (path name)

Answer (score 0):

you have used Toast 2 times 1 inside Activity and 1 inside the fragment I think you only need the toast inside the fragment so can remove the toast from Activity.

Comment: Tried that but now I get MainActivityFragment: null and then MainActivityFragment: (path value).

Comment: In your activity class try writing                                                                             
 val myDir = File(getApplicationContext()?.getExternalFilesDir(null)?.toString() + "/")
        // below line displays the path
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "MainActivity: " + myDir.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
 code after setContentView() method once.